# Android AsyncTask sending UDP packet

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask, udp

I want to use asynctask to send a datagram packet, but it not work!!

I have add all permission that may need!

I think that the problem may be in the asynctask of

```
      socket.send(packet);
```

please help me solve this :)

```
  "In my XML file"
  <uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-   permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"></uses-permission>



public class DroneMain extends Activity {
String at_cmd = "";
String action = "";
FloatBuffer fb=null;
IntBuffer ib=null;
int   PORT=5556;
float speed = (float)0.1;
int   seq = 1;
public Handler handler ;
InetAddress    inet_addr;
DatagramSocket socket;
public Button btnForward,btnBackward,btnLeft,btnRight
       ,btnEmrgency,btnTakeoff,btnLanding,btnUp,btnDown;
   ///////////////////////////////////////MAIN//////////////////////////////////////
   @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_drone_main);

 /////////////////////Button Finder//////////////////////
       btnForward=(Button)findViewById(R.id.forwardBtn);
       btnBackward=(Button)findViewById(R.id.backwardBtn);
       btnLeft=(Button)findViewById(R.id.LeftBtn);
       btnRight=(Button)findViewById(R.id.downBtn);
       btnUp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.upBtn);
       btnDown=(Button)findViewById(R.id.downBtn);
       btnEmrgency=(Button)findViewById(R.id.emergencyBtn);
       btnTakeoff=(Button)findViewById(R.id.takeoffBtn);
       btnLanding=(Button)findViewById(R.id.LandingBtn);
 /////////////////////Button Listener///////////////////////
       btnForward.setOnClickListener(btnForwardListener);
       btnBackward.setOnClickListener(BackwardListener);
       btnLeft.setOnClickListener(btnLeftListener);
       btnRight.setOnClickListener(btnRightListener);
       btnUp.setOnClickListener(btnUpListener);
       btnDown.setOnClickListener(btnDownListener);
       btnEmrgency.setOnClickListener(btnEmrgencyListener);
       btnTakeoff.setOnClickListener(btnTakeoffListener);
       btnLanding.setOnClickListener(btnLandingListener);
       Log.e("///","end of on create");
}
 ///////////////////////////////////////end of on create
 public int intOfFloat(float f) {
    /*fb.put(0, f);
    return ib.get(0);*/
    if(fb != null) fb.put(0, f);
    if(ib != null) return ib.get(0);
    else return 0;
 }

 public Button.OnClickListener btnForwardListener=
    new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Log.e("///button","forward_enter1");
        action = "Go Forward (pitch+)";         
            at_cmd = "AT*PCMD=" + (seq++) + ",1," + intOfFloat(speed)+ ",0,0,0";                
        new ATcommandThread().execute();            
    }

};

public Button.OnClickListener BackwardListener=
    new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        action = "Go Backward (pitch-)";
            at_cmd = "AT*PCMD=" + (seq++) + ",1," + intOfFloat(-speed) + ",0,0,0";      
        //AT*PCMD=1,0,1036831949,0,0 'backward
            new ATcommandThread().execute();            

    }

};

public Button.OnClickListener btnLeftListener=
    new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
         action = "Go Left (roll-)";
         // at_cmd = "AT*PCMD=" + (seq++) + ",1,0," + intOfFloat(-speed) + ",0,0";
         at_cmd = "AT*PCMD=" + (seq++) + ",1," + intOfFloat(-speed)+",0,0,0";
         //AT*PCMD=1,-1110651699,0,0,0 'safe left
         new ATcommandThread().execute();           
    }

};

public Button.OnClickListener btnRightListener=
    new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
         action = "Go Right (roll+)";
         at_cmd = "AT*PCMD=" + (seq++) + ",1," + intOfFloat(+speed) + ",0,0,0";
         //AT*PCMD=1,1036831949,0,0,0 ' safe right
         Log.e("AT*PCMD",at_cmd);
         new ATcommandThread().execute();           

    }

};

public Button.OnClickListener btnUpListener=
    new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
          action = "Go Up (gaz+)";
          at_cmd = "AT*PCMD=" + (seq++) + ",1,0,0," + intOfFloat(speed) + ",0";
          new ATcommandThread().execute();          
    }

};

public Button.OnClickListener btnDownListener=
    new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
         action = "Go Down (gaz-)";
         at_cmd = "AT*PCMD=" + (seq++) + ",1,0,0," + intOfFloat(-speed) + ",0";
         //Move the drone Sets the reference for the horizontal plane
         new ATcommandThread().execute();           

    }

};

public Button.OnClickListener btnEmrgencyListener=
    new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        action = "Emergency";
        at_cmd = "AT*REF=" + (seq++) + ",290717952";
        new ATcommandThread().execute();            

    }

};

public Button.OnClickListener btnTakeoffListener=
    new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        action = "Takeoff";
        at_cmd = "AT*REF=" + (seq++) + ",290718208";
        new ATcommandThread().execute();            

    }

};

public Button.OnClickListener btnLandingListener=

    new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        action = "Landing";
        at_cmd = "AT*REF=" + (seq++) + ",290717696";
        new ATcommandThread().execute();            

    }

};
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_drone_main, menu);     
    return true;
}

public class ATcommandThread extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>{

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        byte [] ip_bytes = new byte[] {(byte)192,(byte)168,(byte)1,(byte)1};
        try {
            inet_addr = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip_bytes );
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("AT command: ","at_cmd)");    
        byte[] buffer = (at_cmd + "\r").getBytes();
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length,     inet_addr, PORT);
            try {
                socket.send(packet);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        Log.e("///send at command","at command topic");
        return null;
    } 
}
```

}

```
 01-24 10:57:26.449: E/Trace(1356): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
 01-24 10:57:26.948: E////(1356): end of on create
 01-24 10:57:27.109: D/gralloc_goldfish(1356): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
 01-24 10:57:27.189: I/ActivityManager(160): Displayed  com.example.dronedivideandroid/.DroneMain: +1s232ms
 01-24 10:57:36.419: E////button(1356): forward_enter1
 01-24 10:57:36.419: E/AT command:(1356): at_cmd) 
 01-24 10:57:36.429: W/dalvikvm(1356): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
 01-24 10:57:36.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1356): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
 01-24 10:57:36.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1356): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 01-24 10:57:36.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
 01-24 10:57:36.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
 01-24 10:57:36.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
 01-24 10:57:36.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
 01-24 10:57:36.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
 01-24 10:57:36.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
 01-24 10:57:36.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
 01-24 10:57:36.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
 01-24 10:57:36.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 01-24 10:57:36.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1356): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 01-24 10:57:36.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):    at com.example.dronedivideandroid.DroneMain$ATcommandThread.doInBackground(DroneMain.java:201)
 01-24 10:57:36.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):    at com.example.dronedivideandroid.DroneMain$ATcommandThread.doInBackground(DroneMain.java:1)
 01-24 10:57:36.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
 01-24 10:57:36.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
 01-24 10:57:36.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, well you need to actually allocate the socket, the exception is a null pointer because you declared the socket but did not allocate it before using it.  Now, this should work, but you will be constantly allocating a new socket.  You should take the line: socket = new DatagramSocket() that I inserted below and put that in the onCreate most likely.

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        byte [] ip_bytes = new byte[] {(byte)192,(byte)168,(byte)1,(byte)1};
        try {
            inet_addr = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip_bytes );
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("AT command: ","at_cmd)");    
        byte[] buffer = (at_cmd + "\r").getBytes();
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length,     inet_addr, PORT);
            try {
                socket= new DatagramSocket();
                socket.send(packet);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        Log.e("///send at command","at command topic");
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialized your `socket`

```
public ATcommandThread()
{

  socket = new DatagramSocket();
}
```