# Main-Thread freezes when receiving DatagramPacket per Socket (UDP)

Tags: java, android, sockets

A simple setup for testing purpose: I am intentionally waiting on a `DatagramPacket`, which will never arrive as there is no counterpart socket answering. But it freezes the UI also it runs on a seperate Thread inside a `LocalService`.
It runs fine if the `socket.receive(paket);...}` is removed. 
Here the `run()`  which is inside `BackgroundService extends Service  {...class ClientSocketThread extends Thread{...run()...}...}`

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        try {
            String stringSend = "hello from ClientSocketThread";
            buffer = stringSend.getBytes();
            packet.setData(buffer); //on init its empty
            socket.send(packet);

            socket.receive(packet);
            String received = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
            Log.e("BackgroundService ", "received "+received);                
        } catch (Exception e) {              
            Log.e("BackgroundService ", "ClientSocketThread");
            Log.e("BackgroundService", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Android Monitor says [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_MzoTKF7WAiY29oclpfVkZ0Sjg/view?usp=sharing)

**Link** to the [traces.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_MzoTKF7WAiOFltLUtUWGtPaXc/view?usp=sharing). The interesting line probably is :

```
  - waiting to lock <0x41ed80a8> (a java.net.DatagramSocket) held by tid=13 (Thread-4376)
```

**ADDON** I now added a `socket.setSoTimeout(3000)` and notice that the UI is not updating exactly 3seconds. Could someone please explaine why?

Comment: Can you also share the code that starts this thread, and the code that initializes the UDP socket?

Comment: any help appreciated : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_MzoTKF7WAibFdnS0tBajhPYlk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it might be blocked, from the docs: public synchronized void receive (DatagramPacket pack)
Added in API level 1
Receives a packet from this socket and stores it in the argument pack. All fields of pack must be set according to the data received. If the received data is longer than the packet buffer size it is truncated. This method blocks until a packet is received or a timeout has expired.

Comment: not a very good practice to start a native thread upon client's Android Mobile..... check the solution with async Tasks which are provided by  Android for that type of jobs or you could use any other java concurrent framework you would like. For AsyncTask there is a related question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493241/android-asynctask-sending-udp-packet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I previously assumed:

> I assume the `Thread-4376` is blocking the CPU as it forever waits
>   for a packet to come, because no `socket.setSoTimeout(time)` is set.
>   Consequently `main` can not access the CPU to update UI which trows
>   ANR. Is this right?

I guess this is wrong. I did create some kind of lock for the UI-thread and made him wait, but lets leave it to itself. I choose a different approach and considered:

- do not extend thread but use a `Runnable`, the codefragment that implements the task, and throw it into a fresh thread:

  ```
  Thread t1 = new Thread(new SocketRunnable(ints, sleep));
  ```
- modifying the UI-thread policy as I did before is not preferable. In Android Network operations on UI-thread are disabled by default. As I needed the flag the code had some connection to the UI-thread, which I finally could remove, success.